# Is there a way to select any type of text?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to select a `<p>` element with the function `.select()`.
I know that you can select text inside an input element, but I have not found a way to select text from other elements.

I have tried `document.getElementById()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```html
<p id='test'>Text to select.</p>
<button onclick='copy()'>Click</button>
```

```
function copy() {
  var x = document.getElementById('test');
  x.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

I then receive an error message that says 'x.select is not a function.'.

Comment: The paragraph is not in input element, you can't use the `select` method on paragraphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that can help!!!!!!

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="foo">
some text <br />
<span>this div is child of p</span>
</p>
<button onclick="selectText('foo');">click me</button>
<script>

function selectText(element) {
    var doc = document;
    var text = doc.getElementById(element);    

    if (doc.body.createTextRange) { // ms
        var range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) { // moz, opera, webkit
        var selection = window.getSelection();            
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

keep me posted if you need any help...

Comment: you cannot use parent element like div in p tag.

Comment: Thank you! I don't fully understand the code, but I am still learning. Things will be much easier now.

Answer (score 0):

I correctly understood that you need to get the text from the paragraph?
In this case, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerText
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried that method. I still can't seem to select the text, even when using innerTEXT. I appreciate the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copy() {
  var x = document.getElementById('test');
  x.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```html
<input id='test' />
<button onclick='copy()'>Copy to clipboard</button>
```

The HTMLInputElement.select() method selects all the text in a  element or in an  element that includes a text field.

You can select and then copy only things that are included in text fields, your text is in a `div`.

By transforming that `div` into an `input` you can copy to clipboard the text that you just inputed into the text field.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select